# Stripe subscription through checkout session

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, subscription

When creating a subscription on stripe using `$stripe->subscriptions->create([])` we can provide a 'cancel_at' date specifying when this subscription ends. But when creating a subscription using checkout session no such option is available.

I have to bill one product and one subscription item on the same checkout without individually adding product and pricing on stripe(only showing them on checkout page). Here, I am not able to set an end date for subscription. Any one has any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event, then you can [update](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at) the subscription's `cancel_at`.